# How to understand GetRedirectedTypeOrNull Methods？

Tags: dependency-injection, abp

Why should we redirect the implementation when registering singleton and scope services?

```
protected virtual ServiceDescriptor CreateServiceDescriptor(
    Type implementationType,
    Type exposingServiceType,
    List<Type> allExposingServiceTypes,
    ServiceLifetime lifeTime)
{
    if (lifeTime.IsIn(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, ServiceLifetime.Scoped))
    {
        var redirectedType = GetRedirectedTypeOrNull(
            implementationType,
            exposingServiceType,
            allExposingServiceTypes
        );
        if (redirectedType != null)
        {
            return ServiceDescriptor.Describe(
                exposingServiceType,
                provider => provider.GetService(redirectedType),
                lifeTime
            );
        }
    }
    return ServiceDescriptor.Describe(
        exposingServiceType,
        implementationType,
        lifeTime
    );
}
```

If this is a design, Then I don't understand the following phenomenon:
1.If exposed IA1 and IA2, Then they access different instance.

```
[ExposeServices(typeof(IA1), typeof(IA2))]
public class A: IA1, IA2, IScopedDependency
```

However, A is also exposed by default.
2.If exposed A, IA and IA2, Then they refer to the same instance

```
[ExposeServices(typeof(A), typeof(IA1), typeof(IA2))]
```